# Variables in input questions

Tags: python, variables, input

So, I know that if you do:

```
variable1 = 10

variable2 = variable1
```

then `variable2` will be 10. But if you do:

```
variable1 = 10
```

and then ask for an `input`:

```
variable2 = input("...")
```

and type `variable1` as the input, then `variable2` will be `'variable1'` instead of 10. How can I change this so that `variable2` equals `variable1` after inputting the string `variable1`?

Comment: Is there anything specific you are trying to accomplish by doing that? Because in the end, your user would have to "guess" variable names from your script?

Comment: The user should not know the variable names inside the code, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that you really want to do this, you can use `eval`, but this is a bad practice, and leaves you susceptible to arbitrary code injection.

```
>>> variable1 = 10
>>> variable2 = eval(input())
variable1
>>> variable2
10
```

A *slightly* better approach might be to use the `globals` or `locals` builtins, but this is still a bad practice.

```
>>> variable2 = globals()[input()]
variable1
>>> variable2
10
```

Comment: Better way, use a dictionary `{'variable1': 10}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Very true. Probably the best way to do this, but I was aiming to push him away from the idea entirely

Comment: Probably the actual question would result in a list of user accessible keys-value pairs instead of variable names in the script, but it is hard to see what OP really wants to do.